# Responsive alignment of two divs with pure text for parallax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I am building a parallax site and have problems making two divs in a section become absolutely perfectly aligned while still maintaining its responsive nature.

Unfortunately when the window size is changed the two elements do not behave as intended. I have included a image illustrating what i am trying to achieve. The yellow lines indicate the control i am looking for. The text `THIS IS` should be perfectly inline with the orange text on the horizontal axis, while edge of `SO AWESOME` should be vertically aligned with the orange text.

How do i achieve this?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/76z982zn/2/

**CSS**

```
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

section {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

section > div {
  position: absolute;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.header_container__1 {
  font-size: 2vw;
  line-height: 2vw;
  color: orange;
  top: 42vh;
  left: 35vw;
}

.header_container__2 {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 10vw;
  line-height: 10vw;
  color: red;
  top: 50vh;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<section>
  <div class="header_container__1">
    <p>This is some text i want perfectly </p>
    <p>This is some text i want perfectly </p>
    <p>This is some text i want perfectly </p>
    <p>This is some text i want perfectly </p>
  </div>
  <div class="header_container__2">
    <p>THIS IS</p>
    <p>SO AWESOME</p>
  </div>

</section>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much to say, just a combination of several css alignment attributes:

```css
body {
  width:100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px;
  background: black;
}

#supercontainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);  
}

#container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#a1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
  color: tomato;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 4em !important;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 0.8em;
}

#a1::first-line {
  line-height:1em;  
}

#a2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  line-height: 2px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: gold;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

#a2::first-line {
  line-height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id=supercontainer>
<div id=container>
  
<div id=a1>THIS IS<br>SO AWESOME</div>
  
<div id=a2>
<p>This is some text i want perfectly </p>
<p>This is some text i want perfectly </p>
<p>This is some text i want perfectly </p>
<p>This is some text i want perfectly </p>
</div>
  
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very interesting solution with the `:first-line` magic. Although i am missing the 50% alignment on the y-axis. Is this possible?

Comment: ps: you can work with `px` instead of `em` to have smaller units to work with (more precise result);

Comment: Theres one detail! I dont want to be a knitpicker, but how do i adjust the last part which is the left side of the yellow text aligned with the `SO`? I assume i can just use `margin-right` on that element?

Comment: Is that for the line height adjustment?

Comment: its the regular #a1 line-height (the css without the `first-line` selector); I did change it now to you check the result. You're free to change it since the first line is protected with its own line-height; check this [**screenshot**](https://i.gyazo.com/9a70aa2680826a5e3426f80ca565209a.png).

Comment: How come this still works when i only set `::first-line` line-height. I have kept the line-height on the `a1` equal to the font-size.

Comment: I think I misunderstood it you were talking about the left margin, not the top margin, sorry; Why do you want to change the left margin? its already aligned

Comment: I have used `vw` for all fonts and it seems to be working perfectly.

Comment: As i said its aligned already but if you want to set a different horizontal align for the yellow text you can simply use `margin-left` on the #a2 div

Comment: I do not recomend the use of `vw` for font-size, because on small screens (such as mobile devices) you need the font even bigger than the desktops and with `vw` you'll will have the fonts even smaller (!) since `vw` stands for 'viewport width'. So, on fonts, use `px` or `em` instead.

Comment: And then use media queries to adjust them for the screen? Is there a smart way to adjust this?

Comment: I'm saying that you would need **more** the @media queries using `vw`, not? Example: 50vw in a 1000pixels width screen means "500px"; the same 50vw on a 400px screen means "200px" as you see the font would be reduced (instead of increased) on mobile devices;

Comment: _ps: the answer was updated now with increased precision in pixels and a separated `first-line` line-height for the #a2 element aswell;_

Comment: about the fonts, [**check this fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/7ct4qhte/1/) (hard to read on small screens)

Comment: you are absolutely right, i need to use media queries for different screen size along with `em`. Could `rem` perhaps become handy in this situation?

Comment: at least on [**this test**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMpdXg?editors=1100) the px/em/rem seems to have the same behavior on different screens;

Answer (score 0):

<s>As a quick fix, remove the `transform` from `header_container__2` and set the two containers' `top` attributes to be equal. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LincolnTosi/76z982zn/4/)</s>

**Edit -** Aligned at 50%

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

section {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

section > div {
  position: absolute;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.header_container__1 {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 2vw;
  line-height: 2vw;
  color: orange;
}

.header_container__2 {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 10vw;
  line-height: 10vw;
  color: red;
  top: 50vh;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="header_container__2">
    <div class="header_container__1">
      <p>This is some text i want perfectly</p>
      <p>This is some text i want perfectly</p>
      <p>This is some text i want perfectly</p>
      <p>This is some text i want perfectly</p>
    </div>
    THIS IS
    <p>SO AWESOME</p>
  </div>
</section>
```